# Cannot connect to cisco anyconnect vpn

Tags: networking, vpn, domain, cisco-anyconnect

I tried to connect to remote PC via cisco anyconnect client.

I can connect and login to vpn server but when I enter domain name it throws error "windows cannot access" as below.

If I just connect by host IP it is showing login box but my domain name is showing local domain name.

How can I connect to remote domain?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The issue you are having is with DNS resolution. If you're able to access a share, or remote resource, by domain resolution - but can by IP address - you do not have DNS properly configured.

The easy fix, if your DNS servers are known, is to statically set your primary DNS server in Windows to the DNS server of your internal network, and set your secondary to a public DNS server on the internet.*

Ideally, you will want to fix the configuration on your ASA/Router/VPN Termination point. The configuration needs to pass DNS settings to the client so that names are resolved on the network.

Use 'nslookup ' and 'ping ' to further troubleshoot, while connected. If that still isn't working, add a static entry in your host file. Then attempt to reach the remote device, if failure still occurs - I would try it from another PC to rule out anything wonky with your PC.

*It generally isn't best practice to set a, sometimes, unreachable DNS server as your primary. You may notice an increase in delay when resolving names to addresses while you're off the VPN. The best case is to add that parameter to your VPN device, but this is a workaround for interim use.